# value selected in dropdown when back to this page php through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

There are two dropdown . one loaded with province and other is loaded with district on change the province from dropdown. How to show selected items in both dropdown when error occur or any other reason redirect to test.php page. ?? When i back to this page province dropdown is selected but district not selected..

**Test.php**

```
<?php

    include "connection.php";
    $msg = "";
    if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && !empty($_REQUEST['msg']))
    {
        $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];
    }
    if ( isset($_SESSION['province']) && !empty($_SESSION['province']) )
    {
        $province = $_SESSION['province'];
    }
    # Get Province
    $sqlProvince  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_province";
    $resProvince  = mysql_query($sqlProvince) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function showDistrict(province){
       $("#district").html(' ');            // city
         $.ajax({
            url: "js/ajaxDistrict.php",
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: {'province': province},
            //dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                 $("#district").html(data);
            }
         }); 
     }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $msg; ?>
<form id="myfrom" action="showTest.php" method="get">
    <p>
        `enter code here`<label>Province:<small>*</small></label>
        <select name="province" id="province" onchange="showDistrict(this.value);" required>
            <option value="">-SELECT-</option>
                <?php
                    if(mysql_num_rows($resProvince) > 0)
                    {
                        while($rowProvince = mysql_fetch_array($resProvince)){
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $rowProvince['Name'];?>"<?php if( $province == $rowProvince['Name'] ) { echo "selected='selected'";} ?>"><?php echo $rowProvince['Name'];?></option>
                <?php } 
                } ?>
        </select> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Postal City District:<small>*</small></label>
        <select name="district" id="district" >
            <option value="">-SELECT-</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['district']['City_District'];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['district']['City_District'];?></option>            
        </select>
    </p>
     <input name="submit" type="submit" />

    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ajaxDistrict.php**

```
<?php
    include "../connection.php";
    $res = "";
    $province = $_REQUEST['province'];
    $_SESSION['province'] = $province;
    $query="SELECT * FROM districts WHERE Province = '".$province."' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $str = "";
    //$_SESSION['district'] = array();
   if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
   {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $_SESSION['district']['City_District'] = trim($row['City_District']);
            $City_District = trim($row['City_District']);
            if($_SESSION['district']['City_District'] == $City_District) { $str = "selected='selected'";}
            $res .= "<option value=\"".$City_District."\" ".$str." >".$City_District."</option>";
        }
   }
   else{
        $res .= "<option value=''>-SELECT-</option>";
   }
   echo $res;
?>
```

Comment: I do not see any `session_start();` in your files. Is it in connection.php?

Comment: what type of error you mean to say? And drop down 2 have to be selected by user when its loaded with districts from province selected.

Comment: what you want actually please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Call `showDistrict` function `on load` of the page in `script`

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
    showDistrict();
});
```

`

i think this will work...

Comment: On back button how this function will be called?

Comment: on back button page will load again and this function will be called again.

Comment: first time also this function will be called then?

Comment: Province is selected when back to this page but district not selected

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the value of province and district in session so you can populate it back accordingly or can use cookie for the same.